# Gitlab project doesn't update when pushing to local repository

Tags: git, gitlab

I m trying to implement this solution
I have 2 Servers, a Gitlab Server and a File Server.
I have configured Gitlab to load a git repository from the File Server following this [link](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/blob/master/doc/raketasks/import.md), and now i can see the project in my gitlab web interface.
The only problem is that, I can only push to the git repository on the File Server (/PATH/TO/FILE/SERVER/repository/test.git).
(Due to some limitations, i can't directly push to the gitlab server using ssh or http)
But when I do so, the project on the gitlab side is not updated.
Any solution to this problem please ?

Comment: What makes you think that it should update? Performing an import is a one-time operation; it does not keep in sync with the import source.

Answer (score 0):

Imports are a one-time operation. Projects will not keep in sync with the import source. The solution you propose will not work for your purposes.

Your best bet is to either push directly to GitLab or to push to another git server and setup a [pull mirror](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/mirror/pull.html) in GitLab.

> Due to some limitations, i can't directly push to the gitlab server using ssh or http

Though, if you can access GitLab's web interface over http(s), there's no particular reason why you shouldn't also be able to push to projects using http(s).

Comment: This is not the best situation but i m using an RDP to access the gitlab web interface. Anyway I was not able to test this as it requires gitlab-ee. But I found a solution to my problem. After importing the bare repo, the files are copied user "@hashed" . So I tracked down my repository "/PATH/TO/SERVER/gitrepo/@hashed/e7/f6/e7f6c011776e8db7cd330b54174fd76f7d0216b612387a5ffcfb81e6f0919683.git" and pushed modifications to it.